# Core Data, Initialize managedObjectContext

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm trying to learn how to use Core Date to store images for an app I'm working on. I've created an entity and imported Core Data. On all the tutorials I've watched thus far, they create a var that contains.

```
let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

For some reason, when I put that line into my project, I get an error:

> Value of type AppDelegate has no member managedObjectContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that the tutorials you read all checks the "Use Core Data" checkbox when creating a project:

[image]

If you checked this checkbox, you would have had a property called `managedObjectContext` declared in `AppDelegate`.

But since you didn't check the checkbox, it's not generated for you.

Here is the extra code that will be generated:

```
// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.TimerReminder" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("XXX", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("SingleViewCoreData.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Just copy the above code and add to your app delegate file. Note that you should replace the `"XXX"` in this line:

```
let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    .URLForResource("XXX", withExtension: "momd")!
```

with the name of your project.

Also, the checkbox also makes Xcode generate a call to `saveContext` in the `applicationWillTerminate` method:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}
```